# What is safer and efficient "new std::complex" or "fftw_malloc"?

Tags: c++, std, fftw

I'm using a library that takes pointers allocated with `fftw_malloc`, but my data comes as `std::complex<double>*`.

What's the most efficient to allocate and release memory?

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> * p1, *p2;
    std::vector< complex<double> > v;
    int N=10;

    //Allocating memory 
    p1 = (std::complex<double> *) fftw_malloc( sizeof(std::complex<double>) * N);
    p2 = new std::complex<double>[N];
    v.reserve(N);

    //Do some stuff
    manipulate(p1);
    manipulate(p2);
    manipulate(v.data());

    //Freeing memory 
    fftw_free(p1);
    delete[] p2;

}
```

Given that casting should be avoided, can we say that `p2` is safer than `p1`?

Comment: You have a bigger problem than what you're asking about. The [`fftw_malloc`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Memory-Allocation.html) function works like `malloc` and only allocated memory. It doesn't construct objects. And you should not free the memory with `delete[]` but with `fftw_free`. That you do a C-style cast is a sure sign that you're doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: It probably depends. You would have to profile it. You ask whether a customized library memory management is better than standard c++ one... Does the library even allows using buffers not allocated with its facilities? Also, you use `fftw_malloc` but then `delete` are you absolutely sure it's safe?

Comment: Oh, and instead of using `new std::complex`, I suggest you use either [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Lastly, reading the [`fftw_malloc`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Memory-Allocation.html) reference, it seems to work just like `malloc` but with some stronger requirements for alignment of the allocated memory (which is why you *must* match it with `fftw_free`). What *exactly* is the function you call expecting? Does it expect an array of `std::complex`? Does it expect some other data? Maybe it want an array of [the C complex data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I suppose we glanced at the documentation too late for you to edit your first comment, but it says that like `malloc` you have to cast the return of `fftw_malloc` to the type you're allocating for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude receives a pointer to `std::complex<double>` or `complex double`. I would love to use `std::vector`, but this data type is not supported by the library.

Comment: You do know about the [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function? Or that you can simply use `&some_vector[0]`? And if your array have a size fixed at compile time (like a normal array) then consider using `std::array` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::vector::data` and `&v[0]` work. It seems `std::vector:data` is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 5):

From http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/SIMD-alignment-and-fftw_005fmalloc.html#SIMD-alignment-and-fftw_005fmalloc you should use FFTW's allocation routines, as they provide a specific alignment.  If you don't use their routines (or don't guarantee alignment) then you must use the same buffer for plan creation and execution.  Using their routines allows for better vectorization and therefore faster code.

One solution is to use FFTW++ (http://fftwpp.sf.net), which wraps FFTW for C++ and provides an Array class which has alignment built-in.  Otherwise, you can create an aligned allocator class which will give you `std::vector`s with the proper alignment.  For example,

```
template<typename Tdata>
class fftw_allocator : public std::allocator<Tdata>
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    struct rebind { typedef fftw_allocator<U> other; };
    Tdata* allocate(size_t n) { return (Tdata*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(Tdata) * n); }
    void deallocate(Tdata* data, std::size_t size) { fftw_free(data); }
};

std::vector<std::complex<double>, fftw_allocator<std::complex<double> > > f(n);
```

Then your vector `f` will allocate and free memory using FFTW's allocation functions.

Comment: Inheriting from `std::allocator` is inadvisable. Just complete it.