# FFTW3 segmentation errors while using std::vector container for FFT

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, allocation, fftw

I would like to ask for your advice regarding the use of std::vector container in performing FFT.

In my program, I use a certain function (**get_PDF_CDF)** in a loop. When I perform the FFTs using std::vector containers, during a certain iteration (usually the second one), I am getting a segmentation error / memory corruption errors.

I know that FFTW best works with alignment provided by fftw_malloc and fftw_free, but I wanted to spice things up and use std::vector consistently throughout the whole program.

I have rewritten the function to use the recommended allocation routines - it essentially copies the contents of the vector to an array of floats allocated and deallocated using fftw routines -  <s>and it works perfectly</s>   but it still has problems. It also involves simple rewriting of gaussian_f and top_hat_f filters. Moreover, I would like to learn if I can in any way modify the version with std::vectors so that it does not produce segmentation faults.

Below are the two versions, truncated to their essential content. My apologies if this is not sufficient for error-tracing - in that case I will provide a working example, although it might take a while to extract from the code.

**FFTW allocation routines version:**

```
void get_PDF_CDF(float rbin, std::string filtertype, std::vector<float> field,
                std::vector<float>& PDF_x, std::vector<int>& PDF_counts, 
   std::vector<float>& PDF, std::vector<float>& CDF){

/*===========================================================
Here we go to Fourier space for applying smoothing filters
=============================================================*/
#ifdef smoothing_filters

fftwf_complex * Fourierfield;
float * field_to_fourier;
Fourierfield = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(pow(NGRID,2)*(NGRID/2 + 1)*sizeof(fftwf_complex));
field_to_fourier = (float*) fftwf_malloc(pow(NGRID,3)*sizeof(float));

std::cout << "The FFTW multi-threaded calculations are " << (fftw_init_threads() ? "working" : "NOT working")<< std::endl;

fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
fftwf_plan plan_forward;
fftwf_plan plan_backward;
std::cout << "Creating plans for forward and backward Fast Fourier transform..." << std::endl;
plan_forward=fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_3d(NGRID, NGRID, NGRID, field_to_fourier, Fourierfield, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
plan_backward=fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_3d(NGRID, NGRID, NGRID, Fourierfield, field_to_fourier, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

std::copy(field.begin(), field.end(), field_to_fourier);
std::cout << "Executing the forward Fourier transform..." << std::endl;
fftwf_execute(plan_forward);
/*========================
Applying the filter here
========================*/
std::cout << "Applying the " << filtertype << " filter... " << std::endl;
if(filtertype.compare("Gaussian")==0){
        gaussian_f(NGRID, fsize, Fourierfield);
        }    
else if(filtertype.compare("TopHat")==0){
        top_hat_f(NGRID, fsize, Fourierfield);
        }

std::cout << "Executing the backward Fourier transform..." << std::endl;
fftwf_execute(plan_backward);
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(1);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
fftw_cleanup_threads();

std::copy(field_to_fourier, field_to_fourier+FFTNORM, field.begin());

fftwf_free(Fourierfield);
fftwf_free(field_to_fourier);

//RESCALE THE FIELDS (in 3D FFT transform, a factor of NGRID^3 is gained upon returning to the real space)
std::for_each(field.begin(), field.end(), [&](float& x){ x/=float(FFTNORM);} );
#endif //endif for smoothing filters...
}
```

**std::vector version:**

```
void get_PDF_CDF(float rbin, std::string filtertype, std::vector<float> field,
                std::vector<float>& PDF_x, std::vector<int>& PDF_counts, 
   std::vector<float>& PDF, std::vector<float>& CDF){

std::cout << "There are currently " << nthreads << " threads working in parellel" << std::endl;

/*===========================================================
Here we go to Fourier space for applying smoothing filters
=============================================================*/
#ifdef smoothing_filters

std::vector<fftwf_complex> Fourierfield(pow(NGRID,2)*(NGRID/2 +1));

std::cout << "The FFTW multi-threaded calculations are " << (fftw_init_threads() ? "working" : "NOT working")<< std::endl;

fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
fftwf_plan plan_forward;
fftwf_plan plan_backward;

std::cout << "Creating plans for forward and backward Fast Fourier transform..." << std::endl;

plan_forward=fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_3d(NGRID, NGRID, NGRID, field.data(), Fourierfield.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
plan_backward=fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_3d(NGRID, NGRID, NGRID, Fourierfield.data(), field.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE);

std::cout << "Executing the forward Fourier transform..." << std::endl;
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(1);
fftwf_execute(plan_forward);

/*========================
Applying the filter here
========================*/
std::cout << "Applying the " << filtertype << " filter... " << std::endl;

if(filtertype.compare("Gaussian")==0){
        gaussian_f(NGRID, fsize, Fourierfield);
        }

else if(filtertype.compare("TopHat")==0){
        top_hat_f(NGRID, fsize, Fourierfield);
        }

std::cout << "Executing the backward Fourier transform..." << std::endl;
fftwf_execute(plan_backward);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
fftw_cleanup_threads();


//RESCALE THE FIELDS (in 3D FFT transform, a factor of NGRID^3 is gained upon returning to the real space)
std::for_each(field.begin(), field.end(), [&](float& x){ x/=float(FFTNORM);} );

#endif //endif for smoothing filters...
}
```

The filter code looks like this:

```
void gaussian_f(int NGRID, float fsize, fftwf_complex* Fourierfield){


int i,j,k;
float x_i, y_j, z_k, krnorm, freq, temp =0.0;

freq = fsize*2.0*M_PI/(float)NGRID;

/*=======================================
The input data is real, therefore its
Fourier transform is symmetric
========================================*/

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) private(z_k, y_j, x_i, krnorm, temp) num_threads(nthreads)
for( k=0 ; k < int(NGRID/2)+1 ; k++){
        for( j=0 ; j < NGRID ; j++ ){
                for( i=0 ; i < NGRID ; i++ ){

                        z_k = (float)k - 0.5;
                        y_j = (float)j - 0.5;
                        x_i = (float)i - 0.5;
                        krnorm = (x_i*x_i+ y_j*y_j+ z_k*z_k) * freq * freq;
                        temp = exp(-0.5*krnorm);

                        Fourierfield[LOC(i,j,k)][0] *= temp; Fourierfield[LOC(i,j,k)][1] *= temp;
       }
     }
   }

}
```

where

```
#define LOC(ix,iy,iz)  (((iz)*NGRID*NGRID + (iy)*NGRID + (ix))    )
```

EDIT:

I am now absolutely certain the error occurs when applying the filters. Commenting these parts of the code out allows the code to run indefinitely. At the moment I have no idea what causes the problem. These functions are declared at the top of the program. For now, I am using the gaussian_f, but the same problem occurs for top_hat_f. Also, executing and deleting plans from 1 thread now.

```
void top_hat_f(int NGRID, float fsize, fftwf_complex* Fourierfield);
void gaussian_f(int NGRID, float fsize, fftwf_complex* Fourierfield);
```

Comment: Try the allocator described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360467/what-is-safer-and-efficient-new-stdcomplex-or-fftw-malloc). If this works you know its about the allocation of the memory. Beware of the comment below the answer, I agree with that.

Comment: I think the problem is that FFTW requires _last_ dimension of complex array (in r2c case) to be of size NGRID/2+1, so it's `ix` aka `i`. At least it is definitely required for correct filtering. On the other hand, looks like your `LOC` provides continuous indexing, so it should still access all values inside of the allocated memory chunk. Try to fix indexing and try again.

Comment: Setting a different third argument in creating plans (blindly tried 4 options, so writing NGRID/2 +1 in the third slot in one of the plans, both, or none) always results in some problems during some iteration. The problems happen at the latest time (4th iteration) when I keep all three arguments "NGRID" in both plans. 

I have changed all the routines to be of type float, but that didn't help. I have a loop inside the gaussian_f function to check for out-of-bounds access, but it seems none occurs.

if(LOC(i,j,k)>= NGRID*NGRID*(NGRID/2 +1)){ std::cout << "OUT OF BOUNDS!!!" << std::endl;}

Comment: The error I'm getting when not commenting out the "applying the filters part" is:
Same happens when I comment out the #pragma directive

*** Error in `./statistics_calc.exe': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000000839b40 ***

Comment: I have checked that the only way, in which the consecutive forward and backward Fourier transforms yield an identity (after rescaling by the factor N^3) is when I use NGRID, NGRID, NGRID in both plans.